# Idiomatic meaning or allusion of "twirl a mustache"

Tags: phrases, expressions, idiom-meaning, allusion

“I have a mustache but I have  not started to twirl it yet”

What is the implication of having a mustache, but not yet twirling it?

Comment: "Twirling a mustache " is a trope often used to describe villains in American cine culture. A simple google search renders characters like "Dastardly Whiplash". It's usually done after tying the school marm to the railroad tracks or  while foreclosing on the  mortgage of a hapless homesteader...

Comment: I think it might be pushing things to call this an idiom.

Comment: This is not an idiom.

Comment: It might not be an idiom, but it is idiomatic.